# Get value from JavaScript Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Just wondering if you guys can help me with something.

I have created an input control via java script and am trying to get the value from that control using Page.FindControl in asp but it is not finding the control on the page.

Is it possible to find it this way and I am doing something wrong with ID’s for example or should it be done by setting a key in the ViewState, or some other method?

If possible can you give a explanation as to why I cannot find the new control via asp.net Page.FindControl if it isnt as simple as incorrect ID's which im sure it isnt.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show the code that you are referring to in the question.

Comment: var test1 = document.createElement("input");
test1.setAttribute("ID", "TestControl");
test1.setAttribute("type", "text");
ClientRegistration.appendChild(test1);

Comment: TextBox test = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("TestControl");

Comment: Only servercontrols can be found with [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx). You could set the value of a hiddenfield and read it in the codebehind, if that's what you need.

Comment: Hi Tim, Should that be a ViewState key?

Comment: @RJF: I think you are confounding things. You should first explain what you want to achieve, otherwise we couldn't suggest a different approach. What you cannot do is, creating dom-elements on clientside and expecting that the server takes notice of them in some way. ASP.NET needs to know these controls before the page is rendered to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible resolutions for this:

Use an asp:TextBox instead, in which case you won't even need to use FindControl (in most cases)

```
<!-- .aspx page -->
<asp:TextBox id="TestControl" runat="server" />
```

and then

```
// codebehind
string something = TestControl.Text;
```

*or*

Use the text input, and find it on the Form (so old fashioned, but works)

```
<input id="TestControl" />
```

and

```
string something = Page.Request.Form["TestControl"];
```